# How to Activate a Python Virtual Environment Automatically on Login?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have a Python virtual environment named `venv` in the user home directory. I would like to activate this virtual environment on login. I don't want to type `source venv/bin/activate` each time after login. I want to type `python something.py` and have it always use the virtual environment.

How can I do this in the user's login scripts?

The user is only ever going to do python development in this particular virtual environment.

Comment: I'd advise against it, because of the failure possibilities, but you can read in that file in your user's shell's startup scripts.

Comment: Failure possibilities are all totally understood. This user is only for python development using this virtual environment. I run the `source` command every time I login. I just want to know the best way to include the `activate` script in the shell's startup scripts.

Comment: The obvious answer is to put `source venv/bin/activate` in the user's shell startup.  Is there some problem with doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be better ways of doing this but the simplest way I can think of is modifying .bashrc file if you are using an OS Like Ubuntu.
In your .bashrc file you can add a line to start your virtual environment.
An example could be adding the following to the bottom of your .bashrc file:

```bash
source myvenv/bin/activate
```